# Create Form in Zenity using BASH script?

Tags: bash, zenity

I am trying a BASH script to create a form in zenity.

I tried the one available on official site
https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/forms.html.en but it throws error.

Code and error is as below:

```
zenity --forms --title="Add Friend" --text="Enter information about your friend." \
  --separator="," --add-entry="First Name" --add-entry="Family Name" \
  --add-entry="Email" --add-calendar="Birthday"
```

Error:

```
This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages
```

On analysing I found the error is because of option `--forms`.

Do let me know If there is any other way to create form in Zenity besides using option `--forms`

Comment: I am working on CentOS machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command works fine on **zenity 3.4.0** on ubuntu:

[image]

Try updating zenity